# What's state price vector?

Tags: finance

What is state price vector?.

Please explain me in detail is difficult to understand for me.

Comment: Where did you hear of this, in what context? What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: What means the state price vector, and for that is used?

Comment: If S_0 is a price vector of N assets in the time zero.
If D is a pairce matriz of N assets in n states.
If Y is a vector in R^n strictly positive.
Then S_0 = DY, why?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide all the details - using Latex - there.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I know for a leacture on Arrow Debrue Security assume that we live in a world with only 2 states and a Security $S$

- State 1 - Inflation > 1%
- State 2 - Inflation < 1%

And

- In State 1  security $ S $ pays 1 i.e the payout fraction is 100%
- In State 2  security $ S $ pays 0 i.e the payout fraction is 0%

This collection of states and Prices is called state price vector.

If you have more than one Security than you have a state price matrix.

States will such that sum of all payout fractions $ \Sigma_{i=1}^n P_i = 1$. You can treat them as probilities.  While pricing a security you can consider all state price vector for $S$ and find the price as $PV(\Sigma_{i=1}^n P_i * S_i^{cf}) $ where $S_i^{cf}$ cashflow from security $S$ in state $i$.

I would recommend you read some papers on it

- [Arrow Debreu Prices](https://web.archive.org/web/20120714072539/https://www.math.hu-berlin.de/~becherer/ArrowDebreuPrices.pdf)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_prices)

Comment: Can you also give an interpretation of "state prices"?